# Why no formvalues on submitting form in ngx-modal?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ngx-bootstrap

Please have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ws8qrj).

When you have a look in the console (right-bottom corner) you will see the values of the form. (NgForm>form>value)

However when you open it in a new window the formvalues in the console are empty.

I can't explain this behavior. Why is this happening? Of course I need these values for further coding.

Comment: Opening in a new window reloads the app!

Comment: Of course the app reloads, I understand that. But why is it not showing the form values in a new window? The code does not change, is it? I also found out that when I comment out line 20 of the modal-component the form values are there! So I think it has something to do with this hide() method  fo the modal.